# CSV and send email: DA|Could not open the lock file at /tmp/DAAccountsLoading.lock. We'll load the accounts anyway, but bad things may happen

Tags: objective-c, ios, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, export-to-csv

I'm trying to create a csv and send it via email.
I create an NSMutableArray of NSArray (called csvArray), use the Dave DeLong's CHCSVParser with:

```
 [csvArray writeToCSVFile:filenameCSV atomically:YES];
```

Then, thanks to MFMailComposeViewController I can send this csv file in attachment to an email, but the **first time** I send the email I can read this in the debugger console (it appears when I add the recipient):

```
    DA|Could not open the lock file at /tmp/DAAccountsLoading.lock. We'll load the accounts anyway, but bad things may happen
```

**EDIT**

This message appears also if I don't attach any files.

Dave DeLong's CHCSVParser works perfectly.

Has anyone come across such a message using MFMailComposeViewController?

Comment: Does this happen with any kind of attachment or only with a CSV file?

Comment: Hi, I tried without files in attachment and I obtained the same message, but the "strange" thing is that it happens also when I try to send a msg in another part of the app that before it didn't give this message. Your CHCSVWriter works perfectly, the problem I think is tied to MFMailComposeViewController.

Comment: I just had this happen. Did you find a solution?